# Java Bean validation doesn't work as expected with spring repository

Tags: java, jpa, bean-validation

in my JPA Entity I am using embeddable object like this:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Foo {

    @Valid
    @Embedded
    private Bar bar;

}
```

And Bar class looks like this:

```
@Embeddable
@Data
public class Bar {

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 2, max = 5)
    @Column
    private String barValue;
}
```

When I tried save Foo entity which

- has bar == null, entity saved as I expected - OK
- has initialized bar, and barValue has not range 2-5, expected error - OK
- has initialized bar, but barValue is null, saved and no error - WRONG

If I am not wrong, @NotBlank should cover @NotNull as well. From javadoc of @NotBlank:

```
The annotated element must not be {@code null} and must contain at least one non-whitespace character. Accepts {@code CharSequence}.
```

EDIT: dependencies from pom

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
                <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: @NotBlank does cover NotNull also. You would like to check import statement once. It shouldl be `import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;`

Comment: @SantoshSagar check updated question. I added javadoc of that annotation where they wrote that value cannot be null

Comment: When I check implementation for the code, I can see they return true for null. Looks like they messed up with documentation but not sure.

[code reference](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/master/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/internal/constraintvalidators/hv/NotBlankValidator.java)

Comment: @SantoshSagar Note that that's a different `NotBlank`, as you suggested in your first comment.

Comment: @SantoshSagar I am using annotation from same package as you write. I also tried change NotBlank to NotNull and try save with nulls, and again passed. It's weird.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- Thanks for correction.

Comment: @DenisStephanov Could you please about pom or gradle file? May be validator library is missing.

Comment: @SantoshSagar updated question

Comment: @DenisStephanov I think instead of hibernate validator you should include 

`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>`

Comment: @SantoshSagar I replaced hibernate validator with your dependency but test always pass

Comment: @DenisStephanov seems its time to create sample application then check, I can't see any error, If you have any sample project to create this issue that will be helpfull.

Comment: @SantoshSagar unfortunatelly I haven't

Comment: @DenisStephanov Sorry, I am not able to reproduce in my local. Not sure what causing this.